# Laptop screen blanks in graphics mode (after startX) but otherwise appears fine

Tags: boot, graphics

My Dell XPS 13 laptop suffered a bump today and now exhibits the following perplexing behavior:

Whenever the laptop device attempts to start into a graphical desktop, the screen goes blank or freezes.  However, the laptop can still display just fine once attached to an external monitor.  The strange thing is, the laptop screen works just fine in text mode as well; grub, memtest, failsafe startup to root terminal all work fine, it is only upon entering graphics mode that there's any problem.

Any guess as to what kind of problem could create this behavior?  If it was a software problem then I wouldn't expect the external monitor to work fine, and if it were a hardware problem I'd not expect text mode to work.

The problem also presents in the same way when booting from a Ubuntu startup USB stick: things are fine on the laptop screen until I enter X / desktop mode, and then I need an external screen to see anything.

Comment: May be you have changed the default screen to external monitor rather than built-in display from the function key. Check that if that's the case. Just a guess though!

Comment: I wondered the same thing, but if that were the case, text would show up only on external as well...

Answer (score 0):

If it is happening with a USB stick as well as your native install, it points to a hardware issue (if it was running well before the bump). It is possible that there is something wrong with the accelerator or chip which only manifests itself in a graphics environment (text mode does not tax the system...)

Just a guess...

*EDIT:* Upon more research, it seems that it is possible that a driver is bad. In the windows environment, it appears that there are certain drivers which were released causing the display to stop working once the driver loaded, but before the driver was loaded, it worked fine.

[Intel Support Forum - Dell XPS 13 only shows on extended display](https://communities.intel.com/thread/114224)

Have you tried using the hardware test which Dell issues?